# Sum data from array by parameters php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is the array that I get from a query:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                     [0] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE 
                                    [VARIETY] => ADELE 
                                    [GOLD] => 160 
                                    [NORMAL] => 0 
                                    [TOTAL] => 160 
                                  ) 
                     [1] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE
                                    [VARIETY] => ALESSO 
                                    [GOLD] => 1320 
                                    [NORMAL] => 550 
                                    [TOTAL] => 1870 
                                  ) 
                     [2] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE
                                    [VARIETY] => ANASTACIA 
                                    [GOLD] => 440 
                                    [NORMAL] => 150 
                                    [TOTAL] => 590 
                                   )
                     [3] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE1
                                    [VARIETY] => ANASTACIA1 
                                    [GOLD] => 420 
                                    [NORMAL] => 120 
                                    [TOTAL] => 540 
                                   )
                     [4] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE1
                                    [VARIETY] => ANASTACIA1 
                                    [GOLD] => 440 
                                    [NORMAL] => 100 
                                    [TOTAL] => 540 
                                   )
                     [5] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE2
                                    [VARIETY] => ANASTACIA2
                                    [GOLD] => 640 
                                    [NORMAL] => 0 
                                    [TOTAL] => 640 
                                   )
                     [6] => Array ( 
                                    [PRODUCT] => ROSE2
                                    [VARIETY] => ANASTACIA2 
                                    [GOLD] => 440 
                                    [NORMAL] => 440 
                                    [TOTAL] => 880 
                                   )
                    )


     ) 
)
```

The keys `GOLD` and `NORMAL` can be differents, depend of the query, but I would like to sum the total from `GOLD`, `NORMAL` and `TOTAL` by `PRODUCT`, something like this, you can omit `VARIETY`:

```
Array(
      [0] => Array(
                   [PRODUCT] => ROSE
                   [GOLD]    => 1920
                   [NORMAL]  => 700
                   [TOTAL]   => 2620
                  )
      [1] => Array(
                   [PRODUCT] => ROSE1
                   [GOLD]    => 860
                   [NORMAL]  => 220
                   [TOTAL]   => 1080
                  )
      [2] => Array(
                   [PRODUCT] => ROSE2
                   [GOLD]    => 1080
                   [NORMAL]  => 440
                   [TOTAL]   => 1520
                  )
)
```

I have tried somenthing like this:
`$harvest` is the array with the data

```
//This get the array_keys from the data
$arrayThead = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($harvest) ; $i++) {
   array_push($arrayThead, array_keys($harvest[$i][0]));
}


$arrayfoot= array();

foreach ($harvest as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $harv) {
     foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $th) {
           if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
               $arrayfoot[$th] += $harv[$th];
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

But at this point it totalizes the data with all the PRODUCTS in general:

```
Array ( 
        [GOLD] => 3850 
        [NORMAL] => 1360 
        [TOTAL] => 5220 
      )
```

**UPDATED**

This is the mysql query:

```
SELECT pr_products.product AS PRODUCT, 
            pr_varieties.variety AS VARIETY, 
            FORMAT(SUM(IF(pr_grades.grade='GOLD',pf_harvest.quantity,0)),0) AS GOLD, 
            SUM(IF(pr_grades.grade='NORMAL',pf_harvest.quantity,0)) AS NORMAL, 
            SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS TOTAL 
FROM pf_harvest 
INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance 
INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product 
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety 
INNER JOIN pr_grades ON pr_grades.id = pf_harvest.id_grade 
WHERE pf_performance.status = 100 
AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1 
AND pf_harvest.date = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY pf_harvest.id_product, pf_harvest.id_variety 
ORDER BY pf_harvest.id_product, pr_varieties.variety, pf_harvest.id_grade
```

How can I add the data to arm an array as in the example I have explained?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show your mysql query ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the mysql query @knowledge....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $array = Array (
        0 => Array (
            0 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                'VARIETY' => 'ADELE',
                'GOLD' => 160,
                'NORMAL' => 0,
                'TOTAL' => 160
            ),
            1 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                'VARIETY' => 'ALESSO',
                'GOLD' => 1320,
                'NORMAL' => 550,
                'TOTAL' => 1870
            ),
            2 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA',
                'GOLD' => 440,
                'NORMAL' => 150,
                'TOTAL' => 590
            ),
            3 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1',
                'GOLD' => 420,
                'NORMAL' => 120,
                'TOTAL' => 540
            ),
            4 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1',
                'GOLD' => 440,
                'NORMAL' => 100,
                'TOTAL' => 540,
            ),
            5 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2',
                'GOLD' => 640,
                'NORMAL' => 0,
                'TOTAL' => 640,
            ),
            6 => Array (
                'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2',
                'GOLD' => 440,
                'NORMAL' => 440,
                'TOTAL' => 880,
            )
        )
    );


    $totalByProduct = array();

    foreach ($array as $items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if(!key_exists($item['PRODUCT'], $totalByProduct)){
                $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']] = $item;
                continue;
            }
            $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']]['GOLD'] += $item['GOLD'];
            $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']]['NORMAL'] += $item['NORMAL'];
            $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']]['TOTAL'] += $item['TOTAL'];
        }
    }
    var_dump($totalByProduct);
?>
```

Comment: if you want to remove variety, the easy way is to unset. 

        if(!key_exists($item['PRODUCT'], $totalByProduct)){
            $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']] = $item;
            unset($totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']]['VARIETY']);
            continue;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
$aProductsArray = array(
    array(
            "PRODUCT" => "ROSE",
            "GOLD"    => 1920,
            "NORMAL" => 700, 
            "TOTAL"   => 2620,
        ),
    array(
            "PRODUCT" => "ROSE1", 
            "GOLD"   => 860,
            "NORMAL" => 220, 
            "TOTAL"   => 1080,
        ),
    array(
            "PRODUCT" => "ROSE2",
            "GOLD"    => 1080, 
            "NORMAL"  => 440,
            "TOTAL"   => 1520
        )
);
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($aProductsArray as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        if(is_numeric($value)){
            $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
        }
    }
}
print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, but it doesn´t work! Can you explain me please?

Comment: Yes I used it like this: `$sumArray = array();

      foreach ($harvest as $k => $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
          if(is_numeric($value)){
            $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
          }
        }
      }` but it shows me empty

Comment: OUTPUT: Array ( [GOLD] => 3860 [NORMAL] => 1360 [TOTAL] => 5220 )